# How to tree shake ES6 index files using webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a file `./icons.ts`, which exports:

```
export { GmailIcon } from './Gmail'
export { H1Icon } from './H1'
export { H2Icon } from './H2'
export { H3Icon } from './H3'
// and many more
```

Then I have a dynamically loaded route which loads one of these icons as such:

```
import { GmailIcon } from './icons';

// ...
```

Finally, [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) code splitting is configured such that each icon is in its own chunk.

However, when analyzing unused code using Lighthouse, I've learned that at the moment webpack is pulling *all* icon containing bundles when I load the dynamic route.

Is my expectation wrong that webpack should be able to understand that `import { GmailIcon } from './icons'` is only supposed to load the bundle containing `GmailIcon` or did I somehow misconfigure webpack?